# How to save an JSON object to multiple JSON object - TypeScript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

For now I'm getting an JSON object `formDoc` form data from the backend.

```
      {
        "components": [
            {
                "label": "Textfield1",
                "type": "textfield",
                "key": "textfield1",
                "input": true
            },
            {   "label": "Radio",
                "type": "radiobutton",
                "key": "radiobutton1",
                "input": true
           },]}
```

and for another form I got is

```
       {
"components": [
            {
                "label": "Text2",
                "type": "textfield",
                "key": "textfield2",
                "input": true
            },
            {   "label": "Checkbox",
                "type": "checkbox",
                "key": "checkbox1",
                "input": true
               },
               {   "label": "Checkbox2",
                    "type": "checkbox",
                    "key": "checkbox2",
                    "input": true
               },]}
```

Different form has different components since forms are customized by users. I'm trying to split the JSON by keys.
For example, split the first one into

```
{
                    "label": "Textfield1",
                    "type": "textfield",
                    "key": "textfield1",
                    "input": true
                },
```

and

```
{   "label": "Radio",
                    "type": "radiobutton",
                    "key": "radiobutton1",
                    "input": true
               },
```

How can I make the split work in Typescript since for the first one will be split into two different objects and the second one be split to three different objects? The issue is not split up the components but any ideas how to save it since I can not make an "object" list just like string.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not thinking this is more complicated that it actually is? Each thing you want to separate out is simply:

```
jsonObj.components[0]
jsonObj.components[1]
...
jsonObj.components[jsonObj.components.length - 1]
```

Comment: Sorry for the question I didn't explain properly. The question I'm facing is how to save the split components as new objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly catch your question but I understand this two options:

```
//Lets call theObject to your object
const newArray = [];
theObject.forEach(item => item.components.forEach(i => newArray.push(i)));
// now you can do whatever you want with your flat array
```

in the case you have two different objects (in different const/variables)

```
const newArray = [...object1.components, ...object2.components];
// now you can do whatever you want with your flat array
```